# Vuetify 2: why does v-on="on" work but other v-on values don't?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm using this arrangement of components to show a tooltip over a paragraph:

```
 <v-tooltip bottom>
   <template v-slot:activator="{on}">
     <p v-on="on">Hover over this</p>
   </template>
   <span>Thank you</span>
 </v-tooltip>
```

That works fine, but I noticed that if I change the two "on"s to something else -- say, `v-slot:activator="{ox}"` and `v-on="ox"`, it stops working.  Having one "on" and one "ox" doesn't work either.  Is there something magic to `v-on="on"`?  If there is, could you please point me to documentation about it?  I like to know not only *that* my code works, but *why* it works.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activator slot of v-tooltip expect a prop named "on", you can rename this prop like this :

```
<v-tooltip bottom>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on: ox }">
    <p v-on="ox">Hover over this</p>
  </template>
  <span>Thank you</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Here is v-on documentation : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on

You should also read the slots documentation : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

Comment: So, `v-slot:activator="{on}"` is shorthand for `v-slot:activator="{ on: on }"`?

Comment: It's destructuring syntax, this article explain it well : https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects